# webpack style import brings Uncaught TypeError in browser

Tags: css, typescript, webpack, preact

I'm trying to load css by webpack and use it in preact components (using Typescript). Although there are several examples and all of them look easy I get an error in the Browser (the build goes well):

```
app.tsx?78df:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
at App.render (app.tsx?78df:31)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js?acc9:728)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js?acc9:754)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js?acc9:754)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js?acc9:676)
at buildComponentFromVNode (preact.esm.js?acc9:856)
at idiff (preact.esm.js?acc9:397)
at diff (preact.esm.js?acc9:348)
at Object.render (preact.esm.js?acc9:991)
at eval (bootstrap.tsx?4488:13)
```

My app.tsx file looks like this:

```
import * as styles from "./style.css";
...
       return (
        <div>
            <h1 className={styles.locals.title}>PROPS: {props.name} state: {state.name}</h1>
            <ul>
```

The 'style.css' file is simple:

```
.title {
    color: red;
}
```

The 'style.css.d.ts' is generated using 'typings-for-css-modules-loader' and looks like this:

```
export interface IStyleCss {
  'title': string;
}

export const locals: IStyleCss;
```

I pushed the project to https://github.com/RasPelikan/preact-war. The files can be found src/main/frontend. This is a Maven project since the server components will be Java. So I put the result in target/preact-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war for downloading.

The build output looks like this:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building preact-war 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ preact-war ---
[INFO] Installing node version v8.9.3
[INFO] Copying node binary from C:\Users\pelikast\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\node\8.9.3\node-8.9.3-win-x64.exe to C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\target\node\node.exe
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] Installing npm version 5.5.1
[INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\pelikast\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\npm\5.5.1\npm-5.5.1.tar.gz into C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\target\node\node_modules
[INFO] Installed npm locally.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) @ preact-war ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install --no-optional' in C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\src\main\frontend
[WARNING] npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-4g8BF3gKWBHeM1jAFmMPHofuJlwTUU4iHJ0i3mwXRHwy74RU6VBOgl9kDVMGpapvGcMlVqV5G6v9XmV66Qqd7w== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-4g8BF3gKWBHeM1jAFmMPHofuJlwTUU4iHJ0i3mwXRHwy74RU6VBOgl9kDVMGpapvGcMlVqV5G6v9XmV66Qqd7w== but got sha1-IyEZIhebgfdEh1S3/fykW4N0oVo=. (63409 bytes)
[WARNING] npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
[INFO] 
[INFO] > node-sass@4.7.2 install C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\src\main\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
[INFO] > node scripts/install.js
[INFO] 
[INFO] Cached binary found at C:\Users\pelikast\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.7.2\win32-x64-57_binding.node
[INFO] 
[INFO] > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\src\main\frontend\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
[INFO] > node lib/post_install.js
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] > node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\src\main\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
[INFO] > node scripts/build.js
[INFO] 
[INFO] Binary found at C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\src\main\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node
[INFO] Testing binary
[INFO] Binary is fine
[INFO] 
[INFO] > preact@8.2.7 postinstall C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\src\main\frontend\node_modules\preact
[INFO] > node -e "console.log('\u001b[35m\u001b[1mLove Preact? You can now donate to our open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[34mhttps://opencollective.com/preact/donate\u001b[0m')"
[INFO] 
[INFO] [35m[1mLove Preact? You can now donate to our open collective:[22m[39m
[INFO]  > [34mhttps://opencollective.com/preact/donate[0m
[WARNING] npm WARN preact-test@0.0.0 No repository field.
[ERROR] 
[INFO] added 746 packages in 64.565s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:webpack (webpack build) @ preact-war ---
[INFO] Running 'webpack.js -d --display-error-details --config ./webpack.config.js' in C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\src\main\frontend
[INFO] Hash: e4bfaca42bf58e78e61c
[INFO] Version: webpack 3.10.0
[INFO] Time: 3062ms
[INFO]                                                      Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
[INFO] ../../../target/preact-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/public/bundle.js  174 kB       0  [emitted]  main
[INFO]    [2] ./bootstrap.tsx 501 bytes {0} [built]
[INFO]    [3] ./app.tsx 1.89 kB {0} [built]
[INFO]    [4] ./style.css 1.04 kB {0} [built]
[INFO]    [5] ./node_modules/css-loader?{"camelcase":true,"namedexport":true,"modules":true,"importLoaders":2}!./style.css 271 bytes {0} [built]
[INFO]    [9] ./about.tsx 948 bytes {0} [built]
[INFO]     + 5 hidden modules
[INFO] Refreshing files after webpack: C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\target\preact-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\public
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ preact-war ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ preact-war ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ preact-war ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ preact-war ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ preact-war ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.2.0:war (default-war) @ preact-war ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [preact-war] in [C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\target\preact-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [63 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\target\preact-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ preact-war ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\target\preact-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to C:\Users\pelikast\.m2\repository\at\phactum\test\preact-war\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\preact-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\pelikast\workspace-jee\preact-war\pom.xml to C:\Users\pelikast\.m2\repository\at\phactum\test\preact-war\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\preact-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:52 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-17T21:27:07+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

PS:
I'm switching from Angular 1.4.8 with requirejs to preact and webpack (for many reason). So I'm a newbie to webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting caught up on the webpack and not looking at the Typescript.

If you do, `import * as styles from "./style.css";` and then the `style.css` contains `.title { color: red; }`, then you'll find your classes on the `styles` object and not on a subobject. `styles.local` does not exist.

So, don't access them at `styles.local.CLASSNAME`, instead, access them at `styles.CLASSNAME`

Comment: The 'style.css.d.ts' is generated by 'typings-for-css-modules-loader'. There is this export

    "export const locals: IStyleCss;"

I tried to use the syntax you suggest but the Typescript compiler gives me an error.

I also tried to add

    "export default locals;"

In this case I can use styles.title in app.tsx but the error in the browser is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out. Thanks to Shawn I focused on the Typescript .d.ts file instead of the css-loader and figured out that I had a copy/paste error in the options of "typings-for-css-modules-loader". I used

```
camelcase: true,
namedexport: true,
```

copied from anywhere but it is case-sensitive and has to be

```
camelCase: true,
namedExport: true,
```

Due to the wrong cases the options where simply ignored! Now the styles.css.d.ts looks like this

```
export const title: string;
```

Which is the right way and now everything is fine!